# Customise ObjectMapper to serialise LocalDateTime properly

Tags: java, jackson, spring-vault

I am using Spring Vault in my project and trying to store a serialised representation of `LocalDateTime` (ISO date time format) as a secret data in Vault. However, the `ObjectMapper` used inside Spring Vault doesn't seem to be customisable. So I am unable to register the `JavaTimeModule` that comes from `com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310`.

Is there a way out of this?

Comment: Is the LocalDateTime value a member field of a class that you control?

Comment: @jonhanson yes.

Comment: Have you considered using annotations to override how your class is serialised?

Comment: I hadn’t until now. Thanks for the tip. Will try this although it’s not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted by one of the commentators, I was able to resolve this by using a Jackson annotation. It's not ideal but gets the job done without having to change anything in Spring Vault.

```java
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
private OffsetDateTime createdAt
```